# LoadRelated for multiple fields

Tags: go, beego

Looking for a way how to load related items in case of multiple references.
I have

```
type Accounts struct {
    Id               string `orm:"pk"`
    Transactions     []*Transactions     `orm:"reverse(many)"`
}
```

and

```
type Transactions struct {
    Id            string    `orm:"pk"`
    SourceAccount *Accounts  `orm:"rel(fk);"`
    TargetAccount *Accounts  `orm:"rel(fk);"`
}
```

When I'm doing

```
o := orm.NewOrm()
o.LoadRelated(account, "Transactions")
```

it loads Transactions only where SourceAccount refers to my account, but it doesn't return transactions where account was mentioned as TargetAccount. 
If I change order like this:

```
type Transactions struct {
    Id            string    `orm:"pk"`
    TargetAccount *Accounts  `orm:"rel(fk);"`
    SourceAccount *Accounts  `orm:"rel(fk);"`
}
```

It loads transactions where account was mentioned as TargetAccount. So order is important :)
Is there a way to load both by LoadRelated ?

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/cab8458c1c4a5a3b4bf5192922be620e6dede15b/orm/orm.go#L273), you may want to play around with the depth argument for multiple relational records

Comment: Well, no, depth is something else (the doc is not that good to understand what is it). They use FieldByIndex to get just first field in struct. So, there is no way to do it by default. Probably my architecture is wrong, and it is not good way to have two or more references to same models.

Comment: Oh, just noticed -> account links to transactions, transactions link back to account. If you want those to be automatically loaded, you have an issue with the circular nature of the relations. Yeah, I try to stay well away of the more complex relational schema's when working with go... microservices rarely require complex schema's anyway. Transactions/ledgers in one service, accounts in another etc...

Comment: Account has reversed relation, means in DB there is no relation in this direction. But Transactions is related to two Accounts in same time and in DB there are two fields. For example you send money from Account1 to Account2, so TargetAccount is Account2 and SourceAccount is Account1. Then I need to get all transactions related to Account1. And have to check all transactions and those two fields. LoadRelated can do this work but only for one field.

Comment: I got that, it's just that every account will therefore have any number of transactions related to it, and vice-versa. Getting one will load the other and back again -> recursion. That's the problem with this kind of relational data + greedily fetching the related records. Hence my remark on microservices: break apart that DB into separate services managing a subset of the data, only load what you need, when you need it etc...